# SQL procedure error: Unknown data type. (near "(" at position 211)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I've been trying to create this procedure in mysql but it always outputs the same error

```
CREATE PROCEDURE registrarCuenta(@username, @password, @salt, @email)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO (`Usuarios` `username`, `password`, `salt`, `email`) VALUES (@username, @password, @salt, @email)
    SET @code := lpad(conv(floor (rand()*pow(36,10)), 10, 36), 10, 0)
    WHILE(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `Activaciones` WHERE `code` = @code))
    BEGIN
        SET @code := lpad(conv(floor(rand()*pow(36,10)), 10, 36), 10, 0)
    END
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO `Activaciones` (`code`) VALUES (@code)
    END
END
GO;
```

Comment: In general, I would suggest cleaning your data values in your application, not within the database layer of your code. Also, are you trying to use string operators on numeric fields?

Comment: I dont understand

Comment: Missing a comma between usarios and username in the first insert statement.

Comment: You have multiple errors! It ıs really hard to fix. I am sorry

Comment: You are using the command `GO`, so this is not MySQL. Also at `INSERT INTO` you are not mentioning a table to insert into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the command `GO`, I will take a guess you want to implement the procedure in `TSQL`. Here are some mistakes on your code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE registrarCuenta
(
@username NVARCHAR(255), 
@password NVARCHAR(255), 
@salt NVARCHAR(255), 
@email NVARCHAR(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE code FLOAT(5,2); -- or whatever you like
    INSERT INTO `Usuarios` (`username`, `password`, `salt`, `email`) VALUES 
(@username, @password, @salt, @email);
    SET @code = lpad(conv(floor (rand()*pow(36,10)), 10, 36), 10, 0);
    WHILE(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `Activaciones` WHERE `code` = @code)) -- not sure if this is correct
    BEGIN
        SET @code = lpad(conv(floor(rand()*pow(36,10)), 10, 36), 10, 0);
    END
    INSERT INTO `Activaciones` (`code`) VALUES (@code);
END
GO;
```

Or if you really did want MySQL:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE registrarCuenta
(
IN username VARCHAR(255), 
IN password VARCHAR(255), 
IN salt VARCHAR(255), 
IN email VARCHAR(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE code FLOAT(5,2); -- or whatever you like
    INSERT INTO `Usuarios` (`username`, `password`, `salt`, `email`) VALUES 
(@username, @password, @salt, @email);
    SET @code = lpad(conv(floor (rand()*pow(36,10)), 10, 36), 10, 0);
    WHILE(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `Activaciones` WHERE `code` = @code)) DO -- not sure if this is correct
        SET @code = lpad(conv(floor(rand()*pow(36,10)), 10, 36), 10, 0);
    END WHILE;
    INSERT INTO `Activaciones` (`code`) VALUES (@code);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Feel free to clarify the process you are trying to implement, in order to be provided with additional support!

Comment: Your solution needs more changes to work on MySQL. Unlike Microsoft, in MySQL, `@username` is different from `username`. They are different variables.

Comment: @BillKarwin Indeed. I just pointed out the main errors in the code provided. I can't calibrate it down to perfection if I don't know the specific nature of the requirements. e.g. I assumed that `@username` is an input argument. And also i can't recall if the while loop will run as it is. Feel free to help.